# How to play single audio files in a sequencer

Tags: audiokit

I am using AudioKit 4.3 with Xcode 9.4.1, Swift, and managed so far to get a sequencer playing an AKSynthKick in a classic house music fashion, it is a 4 beat loop and the kick plays in each beat, but i am clueless at adding wav or caf or aiff files to play with the sequencer, AKMIDISampler asks for notes but does not makes sense to me if it is a single file...

Answer (score 1):

`AKMIDISampler` will work for you here. `AKMIDISampler` is a subclass of `AKAppleSampler`, and it has the methods `loadWav()` and `loadAudioFile()`. The noteNumber parameter, when using an audio file, will control playback speed/pitch.  Using MIDINoteNumber 60 will play back the file at its actual speed, 72 will be double speed (and an octave higher, if it's a pitched sample), 48 will be half speed (an octave lower) and so on.

Comment: what is a pitched sample?

Comment: By pitched sample I just mean a sample where it is meaningful to talk about it having a distinct pitch, i.e., a sample of a piano note, as opposed to rim shot.